# C# using loops to generate a table with correct arithmetic relationship

Tags: c#, loops, tabular

The following is the ShowTab() method, how to apply dynamic numbers and result in to the table?

```
using System;


const int MAX = 4;
int cage = 500/total;

int month = 1; 
int adults = 1; 
int babies = 0;
int total  = 1;

Console.WriteLine("Month\tAdults\tBabies\tTotal");
Console.WriteLine("{0, -10}{1, -10}{2, -10}{3, -10}", month, adults, babies, total);

for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
Console.writeLine(  
}
```

Comment: Don't give us the homework problem. Give us your attempt, and tell us, *in particular*, where you're stuck. We're not going to do this question for you.

Comment: @rob, you are right, I didn't want you do the homework for me, but without giving you all the info, there isn't better way to explain it. I mainly need some help on how to generate the table dynamically part.

Comment: There's a [hint](http://debryro.tc.uvu.edu/1400/projects/project07/hints07.html) in the [page](http://debryro.tc.uvu.edu/1400/projects/project07/p07.html) where you get the picture. Try analyzing the sample. It's not that hard to figure the pattern.

Comment: I've already found out the pattern, the problem is I don't know how to apply the pattern.

Comment: the algorithm part isn't hard to me, I found the pattern right away, the code part is what got me,  couldn't find a example, if any of you can help me out  with an example, I will manipulate to the result I want.

Comment: @handoko.Chen didn't you post something?

Comment: @7537247, I deleted it because it's the same thing as Sehnsucht posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I missed something ; but if it's only about formatting somehow ; something like this should do the job :

```
int month = 1;
int adults = 1;
int babies = 0;
int total = 1;

Console.WriteLine ("header row"); // optional (if needed)

while (/* there is still cages to hold them */)
{
    // print current state (-10 width chosen for example, negative for left align)
    Console.WriteLine ($"{month, -10}{adults, -10}{babies, -10}{total, -10}");

    // do the maths to update values
    month = /* ... */;
    adults = /* ... */;
    babies = /* ... */;
    total = /* ... */;
}
```

Here is a dummy [exemple](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fge1la) which illustrate why I choose to use width formatting specifier rather than tabulation (as hinted in one comment link).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but don't I need 2 for loops to do this? One is for rows, another one is for columns? And use the while loop to set the condition like 500 cages?

Comment: @7537247 Not necessarily ; here the width formatting handles the column part, and the writeline at each "month iteration" handles the row one ; that just leaves the while for handling the "when to stop" part. Just give it a try with some dummy values to see yourself.

Comment: the hints for the hw said output things like this ` WriteLine($"{i}\t{adultRabbits}\t{babyRabbits}\t{pairs}");`

Comment: and, if I only use while loop, it won't stop, will it?

Comment: why wouldn't it stop ?

Comment: what about the hint codes?

Comment: That's just a hint ; you could use it if you prefer (you make any change you want, it's your homework after all ;) width formatting can have the advantage to be finer grained than just putting tabulation between "fields" that's why I choosed it

Comment: okay, thanks for answering all this. I put some dummy data in and built the project, it wasn't something quite make sense to me.

Comment: @7537247 I added a fiddle in the answer to show you difference between tab or formatting

Comment: thanks for writting it in fiddle, couple questions, how to set up 500 cages as conditions? `int cage = 500, while(cage <=500)?`. And, at last few lines of code, where I do math How to apply the logic at the adults the 3rd month is sum of fist and second month without using for loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93946/discussion-between-sehnsucht-and-7537247).

Comment: found out how, thanks.